# Как удалить дубликаты (string) с помощью C#?

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте.
Есть такой массив.

```
Длина: 160 см<br>Ширина: 70 см<br>Толщина: 9 см<br><br>Длина: 160 см<br>Ширина: 70 см<br>Толщина: 9 см<br><br>Тип:Беспружинные<br><br>Тип:Беспружинные<br><br>Тип:Беспружинные<br><br>Тип:Беспружинные<br><br>Тип:Беспружинные<br><br>Тип:Беспружинные<br><br>Тип:Беспружинные<br><br>Тип:Беспружинные<br><br>Тип:Беспружинные<br><br>Тип:Беспружинные<br><br>Тип:Беспружинные<br><br>Тип:Беспружинные<br><br>Тип:Беспружинные<br><br>Тип:Беспружинные<br><br>Тип:Беспружинные<br><br>Тип:Беспружинные<br><br>Тип:Беспружинные<br><br>Тип:Беспружинные<br><br>Тип:Беспружинные<br><br>Детские:Да<br><br>Детские:Да<br><br>Детские:Да<br><br>Детские:Да<br><br>Детские:Да<br><br>Детские:Да<br><br>Детские:Да<br><br>Детские:Да<br><br>Детские:Да<br><br>Детские:Да<br><br>Детские:Да<br><br>Детские:Да<br><br>Детские:Да<br><br>Детские:Да<br><br>Детские:Да<br><br>Детские:Да<br><br>Детские:Да<br>
```

Как убрать дубли?
По маске

```
>*?<
```

Comment: Это вообще то не массив, а HTML. Можно создать массив через regex.split

Comment: Вы парсер страниц делаете?

Comment: Это собранная ячейка. И нет возможности проработать дубли в самой среде... вся надежда на c# :)

Comment: какая ячейка? Я же сказал создавайте массив строк для начала

Comment: using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using DynamicPluginData;

namespace DatacolDynamicPluginNS
{
public class DynamicPluginClass
{ 
public static string processDataFieldValue(string s, ItemInfo itemInfo, GlobalInfo globalInfo)
{
 return s;
}
}
}

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9673/remove-duplicates-from-array

Comment: Разбор HTML вручную — гиблое занятие.

Comment: Воспользуйтесь API, которое предоставляет сайт. Если сайт не предоставляет API, скрейперам полагается страдать.

Comment: @VladD использование библиотеки для разбора HTML не похоже на страдание

Comment: @Alex78191: Ну, когда сайт поменяет структуру своего HTML, и код отвалится, придётся срочно всё переделывать. Или если сайт перейдёт на какой-нибудь ангуляр (или где там контент грузится асинхронно?).

Comment: @VladD При ajax можно использовать headless browser. Или напрямую как раз использовать это Ajax API.

Comment: @Alex78191: Угу, но это повышает сложность решения в разы. И всё равно при каждой смене шаблонов для контента придётся переписывать код. И это ещё если сайт не борется активно со скрейперами.

Comment: @VladD некоторые сайты не меняют шаблоны. Или раз в год исправить можно.

Comment: @Alex78191: Ну это если повезёт.

Answer (score 2):

```
string text = "Длина: 160 см<br>Ширина: 70 см<br>Толщина: 9 см<br><br>Длина: 160 см<br>Ширина: 70 см<br>Толщина: 9 см<br><br>Тип:Беспружинные<br><br>Тип:Беспружинные<br><br>Тип:Беспружинные<br><br>Тип:Беспружинные<br><br>Тип:Беспружинные<br><br>Тип:Беспружинные<br><br>Тип:Беспружинные<br><br>Тип:Беспружинные<br><br>Тип:Беспружинные<br><br>Тип:Беспружинные<br><br>Тип:Беспружинные<br><br>Тип:Беспружинные<br><br>Тип:Беспружинные<br><br>Тип:Беспружинные<br><br>Тип:Беспружинные<br><br>Тип:Беспружинные<br><br>Тип:Беспружинные<br><br>Тип:Беспружинные<br><br>Тип:Беспружинные<br><br>Детские:Да<br><br>Детские:Да<br><br>Детские:Да<br><br>Детские:Да<br><br>Детские:Да<br><br>Детские:Да<br><br>Детские:Да<br><br>Детские:Да<br><br>Детские:Да<br><br>Детские:Да<br><br>Детские:Да<br><br>Детские:Да<br><br>Детские:Да<br><br>Детские:Да<br><br>Детские:Да<br><br>Детские:Да<br><br>Детские:Да<br>";
string[] strings = Regex.Split(text, "<br>");
string[] array = strings.Where(s => s != "").Distinct().ToArray();
```

Comment: `Regex.Split` по `<br>`? о_О

Comment: @Qwertiy это паттерн регулярного выражения.

Comment: Но чем обычный Split не угодил, ведь тут нет регулярного выражения.

Comment: @Qwertiy он только для символов.

Comment: Нет: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/tabh47cf(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Qwertiy ок, разницы нет, "<br>" это обычное регулярное выражение.

Answer (score 1):

http://ideone.com/Rq9CK6

```
var res = Regex.Replace(s, "(?<=^|>)([^>]*)<br>(?=(?:|.*>)\\1(?:<|$))", "");
```